# Peano's dot notation

Tags: math-operators

I am wondering what is the best way to typeset Peano's dot notation.
[image: example]

It is a subset symbol with dots on both sides. For example, for 4/3 I write: `::\supset :\!.`. However the spacing and the size of the dots are not correct.

[image: attempt]

Comment: `\supset` is by default defined as a relation, whereas in the scanned image it appears to be "ordinary".  If you wrap `{subset}` in braces, it will treated as ordinary, without the spaces.

Comment: So maybe should I wrap `subset`, adding the points and make the all a new relation with `mathtools` or something. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know of anything in `mathtools` that directly addresses this, but, indeed, defining a new relation is a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Improving egreg's answer in order to remove arbitrariness and to simplify the code, I finally get:

```latex
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath, adjustbox}

% Defines specific colon, period and implies
\newcommand{\pc}{{:}}
\newcommand{\pp}{\adjustbox{clip,trim=0pt 0pt 0pt {.5\totalheight}}{$\pc$}}
\newcommand{\pim}{{\boldsymbol{\supset}}}

\begin{document}
    \[P \mathrel{\pp\pim\pc\pp} Q\]
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 7):

The period is slightly bigger than the dots in the colon (at least in the Computer Modern fonts, other fonts may differ).

You should also center the colon with respect to the math axis.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Peano colon
\newcommand{\pc}{{\mspace{-1mu}\mathop:\mspace{-1mu}}}
% Peano period
\newcommand{\pp}{{%
  \mspace{-1mu}%
  \sbox0{$:$}\sbox2{$\mathop:$}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht2-\ht0}{\scalebox{0.99}{$.$}}%
  \mspace{-1mu}%
}}
% Peano implies
\newcommand{\pim}{{\mspace{-1mu}\bm{\supset}\mspace{-1mu}}}

\begin{document}

$d(x,y) \mathrel{\pc\pc\pim\pc\pp} D$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thé .97 seems a bit arbitrary but it is a very neat solution.

Comment: I am sure of the your excellent answer.

Comment: @Blincer I changed it into 0.99

Comment: I found a cleaner solution by cutting the colon in half to get the point. You can check my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here there is my humble solution. The output, for my opinion, seem very nice the distance of the dots (they are the same), as from this example, using `smallmatrix` with `amsmath` package. The dots are also adapted to the `supset` symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$d(x,a)<r\begin{smallmatrix} .&.\\ .&. \end{smallmatrix}\mkern-7mu\supset \mkern-7mu\begin{smallmatrix} .&\\ .&. \end{smallmatrix}d(x,a)>r$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I upvote without hesitation. I think I'll try to create a package to get a command `\peano{left}{right}` but I'm clearly inspired by this method, thank you.

Comment: @Blincer I am very happy when others are happy. I was very happy to help you too and I thank you. There are many great users who will surely give you a better answer than mine.

Comment: It's a smart trick! I just think that defining a`mathrel` will be cleaner.